# aws lambda service for name generation

Tags: architecture, aws

I want to implement a `lambda` service that would provide me random names (generated using patterns, some hardcoded values and so on) by GET request.

For name generation I just use the set of prepared morphemes, small words and so on. To create a name I just randomly select part of the word, concat it and return result. For example:

```
const nm1 = ["Cor", ...,"D",...]
const nm2 = ["aea", ..., "osse",..]
return nm1[random1] + nm2[random2];
```

Later in another application (running on Elasticbeanstalk) I store this name in Amazon RDS.

However I've got a couple of questions.

1. Where should I store this partial word constructions? Some relational database (RDS), no sql (DynamoDB for example), some key-value storage? For now I just keep as constants in my `js` files.
2. How should I check the consistency - for example that the name is already exist (as I store them in another application)? Should I check it in Lambda service? Or should I do that in Elasticbeanstalk application?
3. Should I use some key-value storage for the consistency check? I store names in a basic relational table, but it might be not good constantly query it to check the names...

As for metrics following @rwong questions

1. All names should be unique across all users. You can compare it to country names in the world for example.
2. Number of users is - well at most 10 (cannot afford $$$ really huge workloads but still want to use some efficient techniques) I implement application for myself and while free-tier aws is still available for me.
3. Number of combinations is ~777k for one (for now) name generator. (two sets with 288 & 270 values, and third with 10 entries)
4. For now cold start took < 1s. And all other executions took less than ~50ms. I use `node.js` so it slightly lowers cold start as far as I remember.
5. Didn't try to use any DB there, that's why I am asking what should I use.

Comment: Do they need to be unique (across all users, i.e. no two users can use exactly the same)? What is the estimated upper bound on number of users, and number of unique combinations that can be formed? Is your expectation of lambda execution latency reasonable (practical) given the latencies typically associated with lambda cold start, accessing the list of word parts (if you choose to store that list separately from the nodejs), DynamoDB strongly consistent reads (for preventing duplicates), etc? Have you experimented with a prototype? If so, what are the findings? Is it on the right track? etc.

Comment: @rwong I update the question with some answers to your questions